# Can you use Isapi Filters in Azure, and if so how?

Tags: azure, isapi

We use the Helicon Isapi Rewrite filter and we are thinking of migrating to Azure. Is it possible to use it on an Azure Web Role?

If I add it to the Web.config then I get the same error as I would on a standard non-Azure environment:

"This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level."

This would be solved by modifying the file applicationHost.config on a non-Azure environment. I assume I have to RDP to the Azure Web Role and do the same thing. Is this possible, and is it advisable?

Please not that there are reasons why we use the Helicon rewriter rather than other solutions, one of which is its RewriteProxy directive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tried Helicon Rewrite on Azure yet, but i don't see any reason, why it should not work on Azure. A webrole has a fully manageable IIS, where Helicon Isapi Rewrite is not installed per default whereas IIS URL Rewrite 2.0 is!

You can either install and configure it via Remote Connection or via "Startup Tasks".

My suggestion to you:
Try first to get Helicon Isapi Rewrite running via RDP. When you see its working, try to automate it with "Start Up" Tasks. This is recommended because changes on Webroles with RDP are non-persistant.

Further Reading:

Startup Tasks: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg456327.aspx

Manual Installation: http://www.isapirewrite.com/docs/#install